# Line of code inside 'if' statement not running

Tags: delphi, if-statement

I have been having major trouble with this code not running as it is supposed to. The lines setting the valuables PTIDStart and PTIDEnd both will not run.

```
repeat
  if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID
  then
    PTIDStart := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID']
  else
    frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
until frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID;

repeat
  if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID 
  then
    PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamanetID']
  else
    frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
until frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID;
```

Please help with this! I am desperate to fix this problem. If you want a live demonstration to fix then please add me on skype: ikyatt.

Thanks.

EDIT: Please could anyone who has an idea on how to fix this, please post the modified code below.

Comment: If those lines are never covered then your logic must not be executing how you are expecting it to. Try either running through your code with breakpoints, or somehow logging/displaying what `frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID']` and `TournamentID` are

Comment: Take the 'if' outside and after the 'repeat', let the 'else' remain.

Comment: that's the problem though, I've been staring at this code for about 2-3 hours now and I can't see where my logic is flawed...

Comment: print out the values `frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID']` and `TournamentID`. They must not be equal to each other.

Comment: Sertac, could you post an example of what you mean, I don't quite understand. Sorry

Comment: Merely looking at your code isn't going to solve your problem. Stop staring at the code and start using the debugger.

Comment: @user - with this order: 'repeat, table.next, until', then 'if tournamendId then ptidstart := '.

Comment: What Damien said.  Also, you aren't checking your ADOTPlayers table for EOF before your repeat loops nor after the .Next statements.

Comment: Just a suggestion for a good attitude: use always begin-end when you have  an if.

Comment: Thank you Sercat! That seems to have fixed it!

Comment: Of course there's enough information to see what the problem is.

Comment: If `ADOTPlayers` is an ADO dataset, there's a much quicker (and more efficient) way to do what you're attempting. However, you haven't asked for that or provided enough detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID do
  frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
PTIDStart := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID']
while frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID do
  frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID']
```

which should set Start to the first matching TournamentID and end to the first NOT matching after.

If you want to get the last matching in End, then

```
while frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID do
begin
  PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID']
  frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
end;
```

Your problem with the `repeat` structure is that your exit condition is occurring after you've read next - before you've recorded it.

```
repeat
  if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID
    frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
until frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID;
PTIDStart := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID']

repeat
  PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamanetID'] // If you want "End=last"
  if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID 
  then
    frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
until frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID;
PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamanetID'] // If you want "End=first non-match"
```

... if you insist on using `repeat..until`

Comment: Thankyou! This one worked, I can't believe I forgot about while do loops!

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is identical to the `until` condition that it is in the very same loop. As such, when the condition is satisfied the execution will continue from the statement that follows the repeat-until, the `if` will never have a chance to be evaluated when its condition is satisfied.

To solve, move the `if` outside the loop:

```
repeat
  frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
until frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID;
if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID
then
  PTIDStart := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID'];
...
```

For other possible issues that you may later stumble on, refer to comments to the question.

Comment: If the first record is a match, you are skipping it by calling `Next()` before doing the comparison.

Comment: @Remy - Indeed. The canonical way to iterate a table would be to use a while loop and check the condition in the loop. Also an EOF check is missing. I just explained why the code in the 'if' is not running as asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this:

```
while not frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Eof do
begin
  if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID then
  begin
    PTIDStart := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID']
    frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
    while not frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Eof do
    begin
      if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID then
      begin
        PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamanetID'];
        Break;
      end;
      frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
    end;
    Break;
  end;
  frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
end;
```

Or this:

```
PTIDStart := '';
PTIDEnd := '';

while frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Eof do
begin
  if PTIDStart = '' then
  begin
    if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] = TournamentID then
      PTIDStart := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID'];
  end
  else if frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['TournamentID'] <> TournamentID then
  begin
    PTIDEnd := frmManagement.ADOTPlayers['PlayerTournamentID'];
    Break;
  end;
  frmManagement.ADOTPlayers.Next;
end;
```

Comment: don't forget to navigate to the first record before looping.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Yes. I assumed he was already doing that before entering his loops, so I omitted that from my examples.

Comment: Sure, I meant to address the comment for the OP. But you're probably right and it was unnecessary..